# Xcode 14 beta: CMake not able to resolve CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER

Tags: xcode, cmake, xcode14

Trying to run `cmake` to create an Xcode project using:

```
cmake -G Xcode ..
```

This has been running perfectly under Xcode 13 and below. But under Xcode 14 beta, suddenly if fails, and I get the following output:

```
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)")
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.9", minimum required is "3")
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

More detail from `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` includes:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.

error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Command-line Tool'. (in target 'CompilerIdC' from project 'CompilerIdC')
```

What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update to at least cmake v3.23.3; cmake will internally set CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY to "-".  Prior to v3.23.3, attempting to set CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="-" still produced the empty identity error.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, and for pointing out this is fixed deliberately and by default in recent cmake versions. I had unknowingly encountered the fix by blindly updating cmake to latest (3.24.2) from homebrew, without understanding why that had fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had run in to similar issue before and I don't remember exactly which one of these helped but hopefully one of these can help you:

1. `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` issue in CMake - https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23609
2. Download the xcode 14 beta command line tools from apple
3. run `sudo xcodebuild -license` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59556807)
4. try setting it in your scripts: `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$(xcrun -find cc)"` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="$(xcrun -find c++)"` ([CMake error no CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found using Xcode and GLFW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380900/cmake-error-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found-using-xcode-and-glfw#comment109839012_41381007))

Comment: Setting CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="-" did the trick for me. Gotta love XCode.